# Assign Line Number Based on Another Row in T-SQL SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I need a select query to make a new item based on a number a previous row in an order transaction table.

There is a sequential `LineItem`, so the difference between ID with 01, 02, 03, etc. would vary. I was thinking of a temp table from a query: OrderNo,ID Where IDs are 01 to 20 and case statement that test the LineItem and if it is between...

ID 01 2834111 and ID CA800 = 2834112  more the 01 and less then 02, so -01 would be its prefix.

Am I on the right track?  It seems like it would be a long case statement.

```
OrderNo    LineItem    ID     Need to Make
----------------------------------------------------------------------     
236201    2834111    01           
236201    2834112    CA800                       01-CA800
236201    2834113    BERRY    01-BERRY
236201    2834114    02           
236201    2834115    MSIJ54    02-IJ54
236201    2834116    92-D-06    02-92-D-06
236201    2834117    BERRY    02-BERRY
236201    2834118    03           
236201    2834119    SACOLBS24    03-SACOLBS24
236201    2834121                                   OWK32    03-OWK32
236201    2834122                                   04               
236201    2834123                                    SBMRY    04-SBMRY
236201    2834124                                    DAWN    04-DAWN
236201    2834125                                    05               
236201    2834126                                   NWM216D     05-NWM216D
236201    2834127                                    DAWN     05-DAWN
```

Comment: Let me try to rephrase.  You want to move through the table in `LineItem` order.  When you encounter an `ID` values that happens to be two digits then you want to propagate that value as a prefix (with a dash) for subsequent `ID`s until you encounter the next numeric `ID`.  Does that sum it up?

Comment: Is there anything else that distinguishes the lines like '01', other than that they happen to match '01' through '20'?

Comment: Yes - There is a globally unique int column associated to each ID, so rather then ID like '01%' = 36221 would be cleaner,  but there is nothing that can be joined to values in another table.

Comment: Have you tried out the answers below?  Did either of them work for you?

Answer (score 1):

IF HABO has your requirements right, you could try this:

```
SELECT
    p.*, id.id + '- ' + p.id AS prefixedid
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tbl.orderno,
        tbl.lineitem,
        tbl.id, 
        MAX(id.lineitem) AS max_id_lineitem
    FROM
        tbl INNER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id >='01' AND id <='20') id ON
        tbl.orderno = id.orderno AND
        tbl.lineitem > id.lineitem LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id >='01' AND id <='20') id_fornull ON
        tbl.orderno = id_fornull.orderno AND
        tbl.lineitem = id_fornull.lineitem
    WHERE
        id_fornull.lineitem IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        tbl.orderno,
        tbl.lineitem,
        tbl.id) p INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id >='01' AND id <='20') id ON
    p.orderno = id.orderno AND
    p. max_id_lineitem = id.lineitem
```

Comment: +1 to put this answer at the top since OP evidently intended to click the accept button.

Answer (score 0):

Start by pulling the critical rows into a temp table:

```
SELECT OrderNo, LineItem, ID
INTO #TempOrder
FROM YourOrderTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(LINEITEM, 1, 1) IN ('1','2')
AND SUBSTRING(LINEITEM, 2, 1) IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
AND LEN(LINEITEM) = 2
```

Then, if you're looking for a specific @LineItem:

```
SELECT @MaxLineItem = MAX(LineItem)
FROM #TempOrder
WHERE LineItem <= @LineItem
```

You can then look up:

```
SELECT @MaxLineItemID = ID
FROM #TempOrder
WHERE LineItem = @MaxLineItem
```

Does @MaxLineItem have to be distinct from @LineItem?  If so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @LineItem = @MaxLineItem THEN ID
  ELSE @MaxLineItemID + ' - ' + ID END AS NewID
FROM YourOrderTable
WHERE LineItem = @LineItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to partition `Row_Number` on `OrderNo`, but this should get you started:

```
declare @LineItems as Table ( LineItem Int Identity, Id VarChar(16) );
insert into @LineItems ( Id ) values
  ( '01' ), ( 'CA800' ), ( 'BERRY' ),
  ( '02' ), ( 'MSIJ54' ), ( '92-D-06' ), ( 'BERRY' );

with LineItems as (
  select LineItem, Id, Row_Number() over ( order by LineItem ) as RN
    from @LineItems
  ),
  PrefixedLineItems as (
  select LineItem, Id, Id as Prefix, Cast( NULL as VarChar(16) ) as Result, RN
    from LineItems
    where RN = 1
  union all
  select LI.LineItem, LI.Id,
    case when IsNumeric( LI.Id ) = 1 then LI.Id else PLI.Prefix end,
    case when IsNumeric( LI.Id ) = 1 then NULL else Cast( PLI.Prefix + '-' + LI.Id as VarChar(16) ) end, LI.RN
    from PrefixedLineItems as PLI inner join
      LineItems as LI on LI.RN = PLI.RN + 1
  )
  select LineItem, Id, Result
    from PrefixedLineItems
    order by LineItem
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

Additional tests can be added if the *significant* `ID` values must start at `01` and count up to `20`.

**EDIT**: Well, that scales badly.

A version that generates additional sample data is:

```
-- Sample data.
if Object_Id( 'tempdb..#LineItems', N'U' ) is not NULL
  drop table #LineItems;
create table #LineItems ( LineItem Int Identity Primary Key, Id VarChar(32) not null );

insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values
  ( '01' ), ( 'CA800' ), ( 'BERRY' ),
  ( '02' ), ( 'MSIJ54' ), ( '92-D-06' ), ( 'BERRY' );

-- Generate some additional sample data.
declare @Count as Int = 1000;
while @Count > 0
  begin
  if Rand() < 0.1 -- Make about 10% of the entries numeric.
    insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values ( Right( '0' + Cast( Floor( Rand() * 20 ) + 1 as VarChar(2) ), 2 ) );
  else
    insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values ( 'Foo ' + Cast( Rand() as VarChar(16) ) );
  set @Count = @Count - 1;
  end;

-- Time the query.
declare @Start as DateTime = SysDateTime();
with NumberedLineItems as (
  select LineItem, Id, Row_Number() over ( order by LineItem ) as RN
    from #LineItems
  ),
  PrefixedLineItems as (
  select LineItem, Id, Id as Prefix, Cast( NULL as VarChar(16) ) as Result, RN
    from NumberedLineItems
    where RN = 1
  union all
  select LI.LineItem, LI.Id,
    case when IsNumeric( LI.Id ) = 1 then LI.Id else PLI.Prefix end,
    case when IsNumeric( LI.Id ) = 1 then NULL else Cast( PLI.Prefix + '-' + LI.Id as VarChar(16) ) end, LI.RN
    from PrefixedLineItems as PLI inner join
      NumberedLineItems as LI on LI.RN = PLI.RN + 1
  )
  select LineItem, Id, Result
    from PrefixedLineItems
    order by LineItem
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
select DateDiff( ms, @Start, SysDateTime() ) as [Elapsed Milliseconds],
  ( select Count(*) from #LineItems ) as [Rows];
```

This RBAR approach scales much more efficiently:

```
-- Sample data.
if Object_Id( 'tempdb..#LineItems', N'U' ) is not NULL
  drop table #LineItems;
create table #LineItems ( LineItem Int Identity Primary Key, Id VarChar(32) not null );

insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values
  ( '01' ), ( 'CA800' ), ( 'BERRY' ),
  ( '02' ), ( 'MSIJ54' ), ( '92-D-06' ), ( 'BERRY' );

-- Generate some additional sample data.
declare @Count as Int = 10000;
while @Count > 0
  begin
  if Rand() < 0.1 -- Make about 10% of the entries numeric.
    insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values
      ( Right( '0' + Cast( Floor( Rand() * 20 ) + 1 as VarChar(2) ), 2 ) )
  else
    insert into #LineItems ( Id ) values ( 'Foo ' + Cast( Rand() as VarChar(16) ) )
  set @Count = @Count - 1;
  end;

-- Create a fiendish thingy.
declare Plod cursor fast_forward for
  select LineItem, Id
    from #LineItems
    order by LineItem;
declare @LineItem as Int;
declare @Id as VarChar(32);
declare @Prefix as VarChar(2)

-- Create a table to hold the results.
if Object_Id( 'tempdb..#PrefixedLineItems', N'U' ) is not NULL
  drop table #PrefixedLineItems;
create table #PrefixedLineItems
  ( LineItem Int Primary Key, Id VarChar(32) not null, Prefix VarChar(2) null );

-- RBAR.
declare @Start as DateTime = SysDateTime();
open Plod;
fetch next from Plod into @LineItem, @Id;
while @@Fetch_Status = 0
  begin
  set @Prefix = case when IsNumeric( @Id ) = 1 then @Id else @Prefix end;
  insert into #PrefixedLineItems ( LineItem, Id, Prefix ) values
    ( @LineItem, @Id, case when IsNumeric( @Id ) = 1 then NULL else @Prefix end );
  fetch next from Plod into @LineItem, @Id;
  end;
close Plod;
deallocate Plod;

-- That's all, folks!
select LineItem, Id, Prefix
  from #PrefixedLineItems
  order by LineItem;
select DateDiff( ms, @Start, SysDateTime() ) as [Elapsed Milliseconds],
  ( select Count(*) from #LineItems ) as [Rows]
```

Comment: The above works well if I limit the records, a recursion error: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."  The source table is just over 100K liness

Comment: @user1529496 - Easy fix.  I've added `option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
` to the end of the query to disable the recursion limit.

Comment: It has been running for 10 mins but no results yet.

Comment: @user1529496 - CTEs often scale badly.  I've revised the answer to include an updated version of the CTE that generates additional sample data and a much better behaved version that uses an unspeakable entity.